# XPath Expression Pulling 2 pieces of Information into One Collection

Tags: xml, xpath

I apologize in advance, I don't normally use XPath, and the only experience I get is through a tool, that unfortunately can't do what I'm looking for.

I have this set of data.

```
<Result>
    <rs:data ItemCount="3">
        <z:row ows_ID="5" Section="Readings" SubSection="None" />
        <z:row ows_ID="6" Section="How To" SubSection="Meter Read" />
        <z:row ows_ID="7" Section="Customer Experience" subSection="Email" />
    </rs:data>
</Result>
```

I need to be able to store Section and Subsection in the same collection. I'm not sure how XPath typically works, and my tool stores things in a collection after the operation is complete.

I think just the XPath expression is what I need and then I can work it from there.

I have these two expressions that work individually. I was wondering if there was a way to combine them, and store them both in the same output.

`/defaultNS:Result/rs:data/z:row/@Section`
`/defaultNS:Result/rs:data/z:row/@SubSection`

Edit changed Query and Strings to expression.

Comment: Please tell us what tool you are using. Also, if there are prefixed elements (`z:row`) the namespaces must be declared somewhere. The document you show would be malformed without them. In XPath, there are no collections - so please describe and show more clearly what you mean by it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Again, I said just the expression if there is one, is possible. would it be `defaultNS:Result/rs:data/z:row///@SubSection/@Section` or is something like this possible, how do i return two attribute values, in one row*?

Comment: This is pointless if you don't say what tool you are working with: "Please tell us what tool you are using."

Comment: try to use **|** : `/defaultNS:Result/rs:data/z:row/@Section | /defaultNS:Result/rs:data/z:row/@SubSection`

Comment: The pipe WORKED. Great thanks.

Comment: This is not how Stackoverflow is supposed to work. You should give us all the information we need instead of making us guess and then just report that one of the guesses worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe* (and that's a serious maybe) you mean something like

```
/defaultNS:Result/rs:data/z:row/@*[name() = 'Section' or name() = 'SubSection']
```

But we really need to know what language or tool you are using XPath with.